# Why does celery retry, but my job did not fail?

Tags: python, socket.io, rabbitmq, celery, session-timeout

I have a celery job to run MySQL databases, however, it always got `Lock Wait Timeout`. After digging into the databases queries, I realized that celery triggered another job after 1800 sec, and got my databases issue. I don't know why – my job did not fail yet!

```
@celery.task(bind=True, acks_late=True)
def etl_pipeline(dev=dev, test=test):
```

I can tell that MySQL got the same query again, it could be that Celery triggers the same job. Why here I got retry, and the default retry is 180 sec (3 min).

Here is official doc:

> default_retry_delay = 180
>
> Default time in seconds before a retry of the task should be executed. 3 minutes by default.

But my case is 1800 sec.

Also, my broker got some other warning, I'm not sure if this is related:

> The AMQP result backend is scheduled for deprecation in version 4.0 and removal in version v5.0. Please use RPC backend or a persistent backend.

Config RabbitMq

```
RABBITMQ_SERVER = 'amqp://{}:{}@{}'.format(
    os.getenv('RABBITMQ_USER'),
    os.getenv('RABBITMQ_PASS'),
    os.getenv('RABBITMQ_HOST')
)
broker_url = '{}/{}'.format(
    RABBITMQ_SERVER,
    os.getenv('RABBITMQ_VHOST'),
)
backend = 'amqp'
```

How can I solve this? Thank you!

> Celery: 4.2.0

```
I am using job = chain(single_job), but i only have one single_job job() starting the job.

mysql> show processlist;
+-------+------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| Id    | User | Host          | db               | Command | Time | State     |
+-------+------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+-----------+
| 97189 | clp  | 172.11.17.202 | bain_ai_database | Query   |    0 | init      |
| 97488 | clp  | 172.11.11.252 | bain_ai_database | Query   | 1505 | executing |
| 97489 | clp  | 172.11.11.252 | bain_ai_database | Sleep   | 1851 |           |
| 97543 | clp  | 172.21.6.242  | bain_ai_database | Query   |   51 | updating  |
| 97544 | clp  | 172.21.6.242  | bain_ai_database | Sleep   |   51 |           |
+-------+------+---------------+------------------+---------+------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you execute the sql query, here is what I would try.  (1) since you have `bind=True`, the task should be the first parameter to your function.  The convention in celery is to call that first parameter `self`.  (2) You want to try and catch the database level exception that is occurring and ignore it.

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

log = get_task_logger(__name__)


@celery.task(bind=True, acks_late=True)
def etl_pipeline(self, dev=dev, test=test):
    try:
        # try querying the database here using sqlalchemy or mysqlconnect??
    except Exception as ex:
        # for now, log the exception and type so that you can drill down into what is happening
        log.info('[etl_pipeline]  exception of type %s.%s: %s', ex.__class__.__module__, ex.__class__.__name__, ex)
        raise
```

The debugging that you will get from the logging should help you determine which error you are getting on the client side.

Comment: If I just use `@celery.task(bind=True)` if this will disable the `retry`? I just want to disable the `retry`, cuz my sql query does not need to have `message queue` retry.

Comment: Here is what I did, I upgrade the `celery==4.4.2`, add a cache `global duplicated = False` and delete `acks_late=True`. I start the `celery` and sleep the sql query for `1800 second`. It seems like the worker is the same, didnot trigger new worker. I will test it on production later.

Comment: You are definitely right, I also need to add database level exception handling to catch databases error, it could also the error from databases. Thank you very much for your help.