# When Celery will start a new worker?

Tags: multithreading, celery, message-queue, worker

I have one task for `databases query`. Earlier the `worker2` got logged from our system. About 30 mins later, `worker1` got logged for the same task, pretty much like `restarting the job`, which broke my `sql` query. My question is

- if the `worker2` failed then starting `worker1` ?
- if the `worker1` started and failed `worker2` ?

From my code, I didnot set any time limit? Thank you in advance for any thoughts.

I am using job = chain(single_job), but i only have one single_job
job() starting the job.

**-Updates:**

I solved this bug, if you have the same issue, you can do below.

> Please check the `visibility timeout` for your `celery`

> Please check the version to upgraded one.

> Please cancel the retry for `sql` query, sometime `sql` query do not need to have `message queue`.

Answer (score 1):

There are about eighteen different scenarios that could cause what you describe.  The three most common:

1. someone scheduled your job to run on a schedule that occurred at both times
2. someone / something else kicked off another instance of your task
3. the task call failed somewhere which tirggered a retry that ran about 30 minutes later.

Comment: Hi, can you pls take a look at the `mysql` above?  1800 seconds later, a new worker started, but my first query didnot finish yet.

Comment: There's usually a timeout error that gets thrown on the python side for long-executing queries, and there is also a [task time limit in celery that might be set](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#task-time-limit).  Either one of those could cause the task to retry before the query is done on the mysql side because the python side may have already seen the exception.  Your best bet is to add a try-except to the task that is failing and log any exceptions to confirm whether there is an unexpected exception happening because of a timeout.

Comment: Thank you. It consistently retry after 1800s. I didnot set any `task_time_limit` , that means the timeout from celery side is not an issue? My previous celery version is `4.2.0`, now I updated to 4.4.0 and disabled `acks_late=False`. I just want to avoid the retry and figure out if it is databases issue or python timeout. I am so confused.

Comment: Can you please post a skeleton of your task code using `select current_date()` as the query?

Comment: Above is the `sql` query, Table `B` is nearly 500 million of rows . T_T

Comment: The task code surrounding that sql query would be what I would need so that I can write the debugging steps into it for you.  If you could provide that, I'll mark it up with the additional debugging output that can maybe help us understand what the issue might be.

Comment: Thank you very much, here is another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68995543/why-does-celery-retry-but-my-job-did-not-fail